# showing the autohiding windows taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

I have defined the windows taskbar as auto-hiding. Now I am showing for a way to show the taskbar from C#-code. Can somebody help me perhaps with a little code-snipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taskbar in an AppBar. Which can be controlled using the [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Here is a separate article on AppBar's which can help you better understand how to use the API:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3

**Edit:**
If you need to find the handle for the Taskbar itself, you can use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. The taskbar is named "`Shell_traywnd`"